# Apache HTTP Server 2.2 and JBOSS EAP 6.4 ReverseProxy fails

Tags: apache, jboss-eap-6

I have set up Apache HTTP server 2.2 binaries in RHEL6 and also JBOSS EAP 6.4 where my web application is deployed.

Trying to proxy the requests to my application deployed in Jboss, all the requests are routed to application server and the application works fine if i am connected to the same network. Since **reverse proxy fails** i am unable to access the application from internet.

I tried the steps suggested in all possible blogs available in google.

My httpd.conf file is as below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName abc.com
   LogLevel debug  rewrite:trace3
   ErrorLog logs/MyWebApp_httpd-error.log
   CustomLog logs/MyWebApp_httpd-access.log common
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteLog logs/MyWebApp_rewrite.log
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyRequests off 
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://192.168.0.1:8081/MyWebApp/$1
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.1:8081/MyWebApp/
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't see error in the log files too.

Is there any specific configuration to be done for Jboss and HTTP server?